# Two servers mails

Tags: linux, postfix, unix, smtp, pop3

is that it is possible to have two mail servers in parallel, ie a primary through which mails are routed to the outside and a secondary for the exchange of mails locally. and the two servers are connected. In the secondary server was a copy of messages! who can help me please

Comment: Your question is too broad right now. [SF] is for Professional System Administrator (et al) only. If you're trying to solve a specific problem, please list that. We are here to help you do your job, not do it all for you. If you can, edit the question, then flag for reopening. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Except for 'In the secondary server was a copy of messages' part, which I don't understand at all. Please clarify that.